ROS1 slam_toolbox map has lots of ghosted walls
I am using slam_toolbox on ROS1 noetic with a ydlidar. I've tried running slam_toolbox on the robot itself as well as on the remote computer. I am using the asynch online scenario.
It is working but there's something weird about the map being created.

It is relatively correct but you can see in many places where a wall is doubled, and that corresponds often to a situation where I rotated the robot during mapping.

Any immediate idea on what's going on?
Is there any specific guideline about how fast to move the robot during mapping, avoiding going over a specific spot again, etc?
Is this expected and should I try offline?


Any sort of movement based distortion will come down to a few factors. Here, this can be due to how the lidar is actually mounted. Movement/sway in the physical device can cause odd looking maps when all transforms assume static offsets; and this can be made worse the higher the sample rate.
For "double walls" where they have the same orientation but are offset, this indicates a problem with your frame transforms. For example, if you're not producing odometry quick enough your pointcloud will be transformed off an incorrect RPY. In a proper system rotation speed is irrelevant (so long as it's not much greater than your sample rate).
It's hard to say without seeing code (and the room you're trying to map), but I would be pretty confident in saying 1) your transforms are wrong (maybe not updating quick enough) and 2) you're probably not doing enough z-plane filtering on the PointCloud2 msg (hence you might be seeing the floor).
